# How I add a tooltip for each item in a spark combo box

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I want to show tool tip on each item in Spark Combo-box.

i use my own class for combox here is full code

```
package com.zigron.controls.extended.components
```

{
    import com.zigron.controls.extended.skins.LabelTextInputSkin;
    import com.zigron.controls.extended.skins.comboBoxRegisterationSkin;

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
import mx.collections.ICollectionView;
import mx.collections.IList;

import spark.components.ComboBox;
import spark.components.RichEditableText;
import spark.events.DropDownEvent;
import spark.events.TextOperationEvent;

public class LabelComboBox extends ComboBox
{
    /**
     * By default, the match is from the beginning of the string only.
     * Set searchFromBeginning to false to search the entire string for a match.
     */
    public var searchFromBeginning:Boolean = false;
    private var searchRegEx:RegExp;
    private var _prompt:String
    private var promptChanged:Boolean;
    private var _autoWidth:Boolean = true;

    public function LabelComboBox()
    {
        super();
        this.setStyle("skinClass", comboBoxRegisterationSkin);
        addEventListener( DropDownEvent.OPEN, function (event:DropDownEvent ):void
        {
            if(dropDown)
            {
                if( textInput.text.length == 0 )
                {
                    ArrayCollection( dataProvider ).filterFunction = null;
                    ArrayCollection( dataProvider ).refresh();
                }

                if(autoWidth)
                {
                    dropDown.width = scroller.horizontalScrollBar.explicitMaxWidth;
                }
                else
                {

                }

                if(dropDown.width < 100)
                {
                    //dropDown.width = dropdownOriginalWidth;
                }
            }
        });


        // Listen for key-up events to engage the filter
        //this.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp );
        this.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,  keyDownHandler);
        // Drop open the ComboBox
        this.openOnInput = true;


    }

    public function get autoWidth():Boolean
    {
        return _autoWidth;
    }

    public function set autoWidth(value:Boolean):void
    {
        _autoWidth = value;
    }

    override protected function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
    {

        super.keyDownHandler(event);

        if( ( event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACKSPACE ) ||
            ( event.keyCode == Keyboard.DELETE    )  )
        {
            if( textInput.selectionAnchorPosition <= 0 )
            {
                textInput.text = "";
                ArrayCollection( this.dataProvider ).filterFunction = null;
                ArrayCollection( this.dataProvider ).refresh( );
                selectedIndex = -1;
            }
        }

        //adjustSelectionAndCaretUponNavigation(event); 

    }

    override public function set dataProvider(value:IList):void
    {
        super.dataProvider = value;
        if( value is ICollectionView)
        {
            ( value as ICollectionView ).filterFunction = firstOnlyFilter;
        }
    }


    protected function firstOnlyFilter ( item:Object):Boolean
    {
        var label2 : String;
        try
        {

            if( labelField != "label" && ! ( item is String ) )
                label2 = item[ labelField ];
            else
                label2 = item.toString();

        }
        catch(e:Error)
        {
            label2 = "Property not found " + labelField;
        }

        var len:int     = textInput.selectionAnchorPosition > 0 ? textInput.selectionAnchorPosition:textInput.text.length;
        var fil:String  = textInput.text.substr(0, len );
        trace("fil, len, pos : ", fil, len, textInput.selectionAnchorPosition );
        if( label2.toLowerCase().search( fil.toLowerCase() ) != -1 )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    override protected function textInput_changeHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void
    {
        super.textInput_changeHandler( event );

        if( dataProvider is ArrayCollection)
        {
            if( textInput.text.length == 0 )
                ArrayCollection( this.dataProvider ).filterFunction = null;

            ( dataProvider as ArrayCollection ).refresh();
        }
    }


    public function get prompt():String
    {
        return _prompt;
    }

    public function set prompt(v:String):void
    {
        if (_prompt != v)
        {
            _prompt = v;
        }

    }

    override protected function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void
    {
        super.partAdded(partName, instance);
        if(  ( instance is LabelTextInput )  && partName == "textInput" )
        {
            trace(partName);

            //var instance = new LabelTextInput();
            //( instance as LabelTextInput ).prompt = prompt;
            //( instance as LabelTextInput ).setStyle("skinClass", LabelTextInputSkin );

            LabelTextInput(instance).prompt = prompt;
        }

    }


    /** Each time the user presses a key, filter the ComboBox items to match. */
    private function onKeyUp( event:KeyboardEvent ):void 
    {
        var textBox:RichEditableText = RichEditableText ( event.target );
        var searchText:String = event.target.text;

        // Number or letter entered
        if ( isAlphaChar( event.keyCode ) ) 
        {
            // Set up the search expression
            searchRegEx = new RegExp( textBox.text, 'i' );

            // Filter the ArrayCollection
            ArrayCollection( this.dataProvider ).filterFunction = filter;
            ArrayCollection( this.dataProvider ).refresh( );

            // Set the ComboBox's search text
            //textBox.text = searchText;

            //Select the current search text
            textBox.selectRange( searchText.length, searchText.length );
        }

        if( searchText.length == 0 )
        {
            selectedIndex = -1;
        }

        if ( event.keyCode == Keyboard.ESCAPE ) 
        {
            textBox.text = "";
            ArrayCollection( this.dataProvider ).filterFunction = null;
            ArrayCollection( this.dataProvider ).refresh( );
            this.setFocus( );
        }
    }

    /** The ArrayCollection filter function. Each item gets passed into this. */
    private function filter( item:Object ):Boolean 
    {

        var found:Boolean = false;

        // Determine if the search string is contained in the label of each ComboBox item
        if ( searchFromBeginning ) {
            if ( item is String ) {
                found = ( item.search( searchRegEx ) == 0 );
            } else {
                found = ( String( item[ this[ "labelField" ] ] ).search( searchRegEx ) == 0 );
            }
        } else {
            if ( item is String ) {
                found = ( item.search( searchRegEx ) >= 0 );
            } else {
                found = ( String( item[ this[ "labelField" ] ] ).search( searchRegEx ) >= 0 );
            }
        }

        return found;
    }

    /** Filter out any non-alphanumeric key strokes */
    private function isAlphaChar( keyCode:int ):Boolean 
    {

        var isAlpha:Boolean = false;

        if (
            ( keyCode > 64 && keyCode < 91 )
            ||
            ( keyCode > 96 && keyCode < 123 )
            //||
            //( keyCode == Keyboard.BACKSPACE )
            //||
            //( keyCode == Keyboard.DELETE)
        ) {
            isAlpha = true;
        }

        return isAlpha;
    }
}
```

}

How do i set a property of tool tip and in which function that wherever i use this combo box the tool tip is appear.

Answer (score 2):

What you basically need is to put itemRenderer to equals to Label

```
<s:ComboBox id="cb"
   dataProvider="{arr}"
   itemRenderer="mx.controls.Label"
   width="200" />
```

You can also create your own custom renderer which contains label and declare the tooltip inside the renderer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                autoDrawBackground="true">

    <s:Label text="{data.label}" width="100%" maxWidth="100" height="25" paddingLeft="5" paddingTop="5" toolTip ="{data.label}"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first approach will throw a compiler error because you can't use an MX component as an itemRenderer to a Spark component.  The second approach is probably the way to go.